# One-to-multiple values relation from two excel columns

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

I have excel file with two columns:

[image]

After data import I have the following list:

`alist={{"Mark","A"},{"David","B"},{,"A"},{,"C"},{"Mike","D"},{,"C"},{"Clara","A"},{,"B"}}`

I wonder how it is possible to convert this list to something like:

```
res={{"Mark",{"A"}},{"David",{"B","A","C"}},{"Mike",{"D","C"}},{"Clara",{"A","B"}}}
```

with one-to-multiple values relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the function "SequenceCases" that lets you select sequences of elements, e.g. ,{"David","B"},{,"A"},{,"C"} and then convert these sequences to anything you like, e.g.: {"David", {"B", "A", "C"}}:

```
alist={{"Mark","A"},{"David","B"},{,"A"},{,"C"},{"Mike","D"},{,"C"},{"Clara","A"},{,"B"}}
SequenceCases[alist, {{x1_String, x2_}, x3 : ({Null, _} ...)} :> {x1, 
   If[x3 === "", {x2}, Prepend[{x3}[[All, 2]], x2]]}] 

(* {{"Mark", {"A"}}, {"David", {"B", "A", "C"}}, {"Mike", {"D", 
   "C"}}, {"Clara", {"A", "B"}}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alist = {{"Mark", "A"}, {"David", "B"}, {, "A"}, {, "C"}, {"Mike", 
   "D"}, {, "C"}, {"Clara", "A"}, {, "B"}}

MapAt[Flatten, #, {All, -1}] &@(
  SequenceReplace[
    alist, {{name_String, a_String}, 
      c : Repeated[{Null, _}, {0, ∞}]} :> {name, {a, 
       c}}] /. Null -> Nothing
  )
```

---

Or

```
{First@#, Rest@#} & /@
 (Last /@
    (GatherBy[#, First] &@
      FoldList[If[First@#2 === Null, Catenate[{#1, #2}], #2] &, 
       alist]) /. Null -> Nothing
  )
```

---

Result:

> {{"Mark", {"A"}}, {"David", {"B", "A", "C"}}, {"Mike", {"D",
> "C"}}, {"Clara", {"A", "B"}}}

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility

```
L = {{"Mark", "A"}, {"David", "B"}, {"", "A"}, {"", "C"}, {"Mike", "D"}, {"", "C"}, {"Clara", "A"}, {"", "B"}};
lis = First@Last@Reap@Do[
      a = First@L[[n]];
      b = Last@L[[n]];
      If[a == "", Sow[{name, b}], name = a; Sow[{name, b}]]
      , {n, Length@L}
      ];
lis2 = GroupBy[lis, First];
{lis2[[#]][[1, 1]], lis2[[#]][[All, 2]]} & /@ Range[Length@lis2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
{#[[1]],#2}&@@@Partition[
 SplitBy[Flatten[
   DeleteCases[#,Null]&/@alist],
    Length@Characters@#&],2]
```